# ./lua/addtest.lua:9: attempt to index local 'testobj' (a userdata value)]]

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api, lua-userdata

test.exe call addTest.lua and set the `lua_testobj` to the table, and addTest.lua call testobj.dll,
but testobj.dll can not get the "lua_testobj"

error msg is

> addTest.lua:9 attempt to index local 'testobj' (a userdata value)

1. test.exe

   ```
   L = luaL_newstate();
   // link lua lib
   luaL_openlibs(L);
   //
   addLuaCPath( L, "./clib/?.dll" );
   //
   lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)g_TestObj.get()); // g_TestObj is a global vars
   lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "lua_testobj");
   // 
   int err = 0;
   err = luaL_loadfile( L, "./lua/addTest.lua" );
   if( err != LUA_OK )
     printf("Failed to load addTest.lua![%s]", lua_tostring(L,-1));

   err =  lua_pcall( L, 0, 1, 0 );
   if( err != LUA_OK )
     printf("Failed to call addTest.lua![%s]", lua_tostring(L,-1));
   ```
2. the addtest.lua code is following

   ```
   local luapath = package.path
   local cpath = package.cpath

   print(luapath)
   print(cpath)

   local testobj= require "testobj"

   testobj.addTest()
   ```
3. and the testobj.dll source code is following

   ```
   static int laddTest(lua_State *L)
   {
     lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "lua_testobj");
     return 1;
   }

   extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) 
   luaopen_testobj(lua_State *L)
   {
     luaL_Reg l[] = {
       { "addTest", laddTest },
       { NULL, NULL },
     };

     luaL_checkversion(L);
     luaL_newlib(L,l);

     lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "lua_testobj");
     CTestObj* pTestObj = static_cast<CTestObj*>( lua_touserdata(L,-1) );

     return 1;
   }
   ```

Comment: Initial glance over the code, it doesn't look like you've set any metatable for `lua_testobj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `testobj.dll` did actually return your `lua_testobj` successfully because the error you're getting:

> addTest.lua:9 attempt to index local 'testobj' (a userdata value)

indicates lua sees `testobj` as a `userdata`. That's not where the problem is; the real issue is that you didn't associate any metatable with that userdata so lua can't really do anything with it when a script tries to use it.

I've modified your `luaopen_testobj` to create and register a metatable for your `testobj`:

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) 
luaopen_testobj(lua_State *L) 
{
  luaL_Reg l[] = 
  {
      { "addTest", laddTest },
      { NULL, NULL },
  };

  luaL_checkversion(L);
  lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)g_TestObj.get());

  // g_TestObj, testobj_mt, {l}
  luaL_newmetatable(L, "lua_testobj");
  luaL_newlib(L, l);
  // testobj_mt.__index = {l}
  lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

  // return setmetatable(g_TestObj, testobj_mt)
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
  return 1;
}
```

This should allow you to access `laddTest` using `testobj:addTest()` from lua. `laddtest` should check that `testobj` is indeed the userdata you passed in, for example:

```
static int laddTest(lua_State *L)
{
    auto pTestObj = reinterpret_cast<CTestObj *> (luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "lua_testobj"));
    // do something ...
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: but I want to pass the g_TestObj from exe to dll

Comment: In that case, you'll have to move the metatable registration code over to `test.exe`'s `main`. Just make sure the metatable is added to the registry once.

Comment: You can also have `luaopen_testobj` just return a new luatable containing the functions in `luaL_Reg l[]` which would simplify some things since the script won't deal with the lightudata directly. But it's unclear what your end goal is so I can't recommend one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the `luaopen_testobj` function, add `lua_pop(L, 1);` before return

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) 
luaopen_testobj(lua_State *L)
{
  luaL_Reg l[] = {
    { "addTest", laddTest },
    { NULL, NULL },
  };

  luaL_checkversion(L);
  luaL_newlib(L,l);

  lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "lua_testobj");
  CTestObj* pTestObj = static_cast<CTestObj*>( lua_touserdata(L,-1) );

  lua_pop(L, 1);

  return 1;
}
```

Now, it can correctly to obtain the value of pTestObj, no longer appear "addTest.lua:9 attempt to index local 'testobj' (a userdata value)" wrong.

**But I don't know what's the meaning of the error message**

Comment: As I already explained in my answer, userdata isn't indexable without a metatable because it's C/C++ data.